# How to deploy minio to k8s with pre-installed bucket policy?

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes-helm, minio

I deploy minio to k8s using helm chart.

```
  - name: minio
    condition: minio.enabled
    version: 12.10.7
    repository: "https://nexus.inno.tech/repository/common-proxy-helm-bitnami"
```

In the values.yaml file for provisioning in minio I set the policy.

```
minio:
  enabled: true
  provisioning:
    enabled: true
    policies:
      - name: test-anonymous-policy
        statements:
          - resources:
              - "arn:aws:s3:::test"
            effect: "Allow"
            actions:
              - "s3:GetBucketLocation"
              - "s3:ListBucket"
          - resources:
              - "arn:aws:s3:::test/*"
            effect: "Allow"
            actions:
              - "s3:GetObject"
```

This policy after deployment is visible in the list of policies in the UI. This policy can be set to any user in the same values.yaml file.

```
    users:
      - username: test-username
        password: test-password
        disabled: false
        policies:
          - test-anonymous-policy
        setPolicies: true
```

But bucket doesn’t seem to have such a setting. Is it possible to set a default policy for a bucket in values.yaml?

```
    buckets:
      - name: test
        region: us-west-1
      # some_field: test-anonymous-policy
        tags:
          account: "1"
          createdBy: some_access_key-cid
```

Or maybe there are other workarounds?
As a result, you need to get a bucket with a readonly setting for all anonymous users.
Or maybe you can set the PutBucketPolicy command directly in the values.yaml file?

I wouldn’t want to create a job calling a sh script in cli minio. I see this as a last resort option. I would like to solve everything in the values.yaml file.